# How to add custom font to PhpOffice/PhpWord package

Tags: php, phpword, phpoffice, farsi

I am trying to generate .docx file from html with PhpWord package [(here)](https://phpword.readthedocs.io).

I want to use a custom Persian font (b-Nazanin) in my file. I got these formats of the font: (.ttf, .woff, .z, .cfg.z, .php).

Is there a way to add custom fonts to the PhpWord package? For example loading a TTF file and using it. The documentation only speaks about specifying an existing font, not loading a custom one.

If not, are there any other open-source packages to generate .docx file with custom fonts?

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59611477/phpword-setting-font-inside-template-processor) and [here](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/general.html)

Comment: Thank you @SimoneRossaini for your response. I think the links you sent, describes how to config an existing font in PhpWord, my problem is that I don't know how to add a new custom font to PhpWord.

Comment: @mohamadmamghaderi Where you able to get a way to load a custom font?

Comment: I tried to make the question more clear, although I don't see how it was unclear to begin with. Please reopen this question!

Answer (score 0):

I got around this issue by installing the font into my system and then using it as the example in the documentation.

I installed the 'Tajawal' font into my system and then used it like:

```
$word = new PhpWord();
$word->setDefaultFontName('Tajawal');
```